# Crystal Reports /SQL Server 2012 error

Tags: .net, sql-server, crystal-reports

I am testing a program which prints some reports. The DBMS we are using is SQL Server 2012 and the database we are using is huge.

However, when someone try to print an specific report (this problem only appears in one of more than 30 reports of the program), the following error message appears:

```
Logon Failed.
Details: [Database Vendor Code: 18456]
Database Connector error: '[Database Vendor Code 18456]'
Logon Failed.
Error in File Temp_some_strings.rpt:
Unable to connect: Incorrect log on parameters.
Details: [Database Vendor Code 18456]
```

And well, the user closes the program and open it again to generate the report, which in this second execution, it appears without problems.

I have read that it is a SQL Server error, so... ¿What should I do in the database? ¿I have to configure something?

I a newbie at .net, so if I have to view something in the code, which themes I must investigate to solve this problem?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Where does your report get the login credentials from?

Comment: All the reports are using the db credentials of the application. But this problem only appears only to this user. I tested that report and I don't have problems with it, so I need to know if it was produced from a bad database configuration.

Comment: There seem to be a LOT of solutions to this issue here. https://www.google.com/search?q=%27%5BDatabase+Vendor+Code+18456%5D%27&ie=utf-8&oe=utf-8#q=[Database+Vendor+Code+18456]

Answer (score 0):

Crystal report need to login every time you open it.

See this [link](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/68876082-1f22-4bb8-9e2f-52c54c177367/logon-failed-problem-with-crystal-report-net?forum=vscrystalreports) for more details.

Hope it helps.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. but finally, they repaired the problem in a database level. They don't specified what was the solution but is related with a function to disconnect and reconnect the database